# JavaScript for-loop does not return an item and the test doesn't pass

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, return

I am currently learning JavaScript and all my test pass but one of my functions doesn't seem running properly.

Here's the test

```
it("should get record by its id", function(){
  customer1.setFunds(100);
  customer1.buy(record1, store1);
  customer1.buy(record2, store1);
  var item = customer1.getRecord("xyz123");
  console.log(customer1);
  is.equal("Nirvana", item.artist);
}),
```

Here's the object

```
 record2 = new Record("Nirvana", "In Utero", 25, 11, "xyz123");//the last attribute is the id
```

Here's the function I am testing

```
 getRecord: function(id){
 for(var i = 0; i<this.boughtItems.length; i+=1){
if(this.boughtItems[i].id === id){
  return this.boughtItems[i];
}else{
  return "The item doesn't exist";
 }
}
```

The point is that the this.boughtItems consists of that element I am looking for and the function cannot return it. I know that JS objects work in a weird way sometimes but this is very vague to me. Unless I am blind and cannot see a simple issue going on there

Thanks!

UPDATE the Record doesn't hold any functions assigned to it, just attributes

```
var Record = function(artist, title, price, stock, id){
this.artist = artist;
this.title = title;
this.price = price;
this.stock = stock;
this.id = id;
 };
```

UPDATE2 the buy() method

```
buy: function(product, store){
 if(this.funds >= product.price){
    store.sell(product);
    var itemToBuy = new Record(product.artist, product.title, product.price, 1, product.id);
    this.boughtItems.push(itemToBuy);
    this.funds -= itemToBuy.price;
 }else{
return "You cannot afford to buy this item";
   }
 }
```

and this is even weirder, in my tests, the "item" object appears as "You cannot afford to buy this item"

Comment: Can we see the `Record` prototype class you're using?

Comment: updated :) thank you!

Comment: Can we see the `buy()` method on Customer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to takeout your if out of your for-loop.
Now it returns "The item doesn't exist" after the first element.

```
 getRecord: function(id) {
 for(var i = 0; i<this.boughtItems.length; i+=1) {
    if (this.boughtItems[i].id === id) {
         return this.boughtItems[i];
    }
}
return "The item doesn't exist";
```

Comment: In your case only the first element of your array was checked. If the fist element was correct than it returned that object, but when it fails it returned "The item doesn't exist". Because you returns something within your for-loop it stops iterating. You can check this by logging `index` in your for-loop

Comment: thanks for the hint! I think I need to be more careful with for loops behaviour